# FUSE mounted filesystems and snap applications

Tags: snap, sshfs, fuse

I've seen lots of questions asking about snap applications and trying to use them to access FUSE mounted file systems.  But none of the responses to those questions that I can find give or link to explicit directions on how you can get a snap application (that presumably has the necessary connection options) working with (in my case) an sshfs mount.  I've seen lots of things that say "if you mount it in the right location with the right options and flip the proper switches in the snap it can work" but none list the right locations or options.  Given a typical Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install and the Firefox snap that is installed by default (presumably this should be one of the best supported examples), what do I do to enable Firefox to save files to an sshfs mount (currently mounted in ~/mnt/ but this can change if necessary)

Comment: Nothing to do with File Systems. Snaps are containerized apps. For example Firefox looks only in the home directory for files and saves of files by default. Not aware you can do that with the snap version that is why many will remove the snap version and put back the deb version.

Comment: Looks like a possible independent discovery of bug [Mozilla #1773624](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1773624) (though that one is SMB). If that patch does not solve your problem, then please file a new bug report.

Comment: In firefox I am able to open the dialog to save files and browse into the FUSE file systems. When I click save it creates a zero length file and reports an error.  With very large files, it creates hundreds of zero length files and throws an error.  In other snap applications I get other forms of brokenness.  When apps first started being distributed as snaps I had all kinds of issues and avoided using them.  Now that ubuntu is making snaps the primary method of distributing many core applications I had hoped that they had been at least mostly resolved but that doesn't look to be the case.

Comment: I voted to leave this question open because both snaps applications and FUSE mounted file systems can cause access problems, more so if there are both of them together.

Comment: @karel: I've been using FUSE file systems for about two decades now and have implemented them in scientific applications. I find them extremely useful. Then there're things like appimages which bootstrap themselves by creating a FUSE file system to run in. All of these things have worked without issue for me until snap apps came out and seem to have specifically chosen not to interoperate with what I consider to be core functionality (all of this is besides the point of never having worked with a large organization that didn't use a bunch of what snap considers "nonstandard" mount locations).